# PostPersist & PostFlush infinite loop in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, flush, persist

I'm trying to link a coffee profile to a user after the user is in the database.
This coffee profile data is in a session and I'm using this session in the postFlush.

However This code is creating an infinite loop and I don't know why:

UserListener.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use AppBundle\Entity\Consumption;
use AppBundle\Entity\CoffeeOption;
use AppBundle\Entity\Consumeable;
use AppBundle\Entity\MomentPreference;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostFlushEventArgs;

class UserListener
{
    private $container;
    private $user;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $user = $args->getEntity();

        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $session = new Session();

        if($session) {

            $em = $args->getEntityManager();

            $us = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneById($this->user->getId());

            $consumption = $session->get('consumption');
            $coffee = $session->get('coffee');
            $moment = $session->get('moment');

            $consumption->setUser($us);

            //dummy data for the day, later this needs to be turned into datetime
            $moment->setDay('monday');
            $moment->setConsumption($consumption);

            $em->persist($consumption);
            $em->persist($coffee);
            $em->persist($moment);

            $em->flush();        

        } else {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_registration_register');
        }
    }

}
```

Services.yml:

```
    zpadmin.listener.user:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\UserListener
    arguments: ['@service_container']
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postPersist }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postFlush }
```

What is causing this loop and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `postFlush` event, you're flushing again. That's what causing the infinite loop because the `postFlush` event is triggered every time you're calling the `flush` method.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but your goal is to create a coffee consumption everytime you're saving a user, you can add a test like this one at the start of your method:

```
$entity = $args->getObject();

if (!$entity instanceof User) {
    return;
}
```

This will prevent the infinite loop.

And a few more things:

- Your `postPersist` method seems useless. It'll be called every time an object is persisted so your `$this->user` propety will not necessarily be a User object.
- If you need the user, you don't have to fetch it in your database. Simply use `$args->getObject()` to get the flushed entity. In addition with the test above, you'll be sure the method will return you a User object.
- This is not a very good practice to check if the user is logged in in your Doctrine listener. This is not what the class is supposed to do.
- Don't inject the container in your constructor. Inject only what you need (in this case... nothing ?)

Comment: Postflush uses PostFlushEventArgs instead of LifecycleEventArgs. PostFlushEventArgs  doesn't have the user object in it. Should I use postflush for my case of postpersist? And how do I flush the coffee profile that needs to be linked to the user when I can't use flush() ?

Comment: @MarcoKoopman Good point. You should use postUpdate instead. You can use the `flush` method in your event, but you can't use it on a User entity if you don't want an infinite loop.

Comment: I've changed it to postUpdate and now it works like a charm! Thank you so much! I've been struggeling with this issue for some time now!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `$em->flush()` inside your postPersist event, in the [docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#postflush) it is stated that:

> postFlush is called at the end of EntityManager#flush().
>   EntityManager#flush() can NOT be called safely inside its listeners.

You should use other events like `prePersist` or `postPersist`.

If possible try to avoid multiple `flush()` on a single request.

by the way, there is no need to do this, because your user object is already contained inside your $user variable.

> $us =
>   $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneById($this->user->getId());

Comment: If I dont use flush() in the postPersist it doesnt push the coffee profile to the database. But if I use flush() in the postPersist I get an error..

Answer (score 1):

This example try please

```
    use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\EventSubscriber\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class DatabaseActivitySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected array $changeUpdateDataEntityList = [];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected array $changeDeleteDataEntityList = [];

    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface
     */
    protected ContainerInterface $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            Events::postFlush,
            Events::onFlush
        ];
    }

    public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $args): void
    {
        foreach ($this->changeUpdateDataEntityList as $entity) {
            // Do something
        }
    }

    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs): void
    {
        $em = $eventArgs->getObjectManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
            // Do something
        }

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
            // Do something
        }

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityDeletions() as $entity) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

}